# Beautifulsoup trying to extract all game names, metascores, and user scores

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?sort=desc&year_selected=2018"
```

Try to get all the game names, metascores, and user scores on the page

here is what I have so far:

```
# not sure about this but it works (I was getting blocked by something and this the way I found around it)
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

#this grabs the all the text from the page
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')

game_containers = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")

game_names = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")
game_metascores_p = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game positive")[0].text.strip()
game_metascores_m = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game mixed")[0].text.strip()
game_user_s = html_soup.find_all("span", class_="data textscore textscore_favorable")[0].text.strip()

#lists to store the data
names = []
metascores = []
userscores = []

#Extract data from each game
for games in game_containers:

    name = games.find("div", class_="product_item product_title")
    print(name)

    metascore = games.find("div", class_="product_item product_title")[0].text.strip() or games.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game mixed")[0].text.strip()
    print(meta_score)
```

I know I have more than one issue with this code

being that "name" and "metascore" don't return the info I'm looking for

also not sure how so combine game_metascores_p and game_metascores_m to work properly (I want the the game name to be associated with either the game_metascores_p and game_metascores_s if there is one or the other)

any help would be appreciated

this is what game and metascore print this:

for game and then metascore(it repeats 100x):

```
None
[]
```

I want for the first one(and so on):

```
In to the Breach
89
```

Comment: It would help if you included the URL of the page you're trying to scrape this data from. See the asking guide for help on creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is the actual and what is the expected output? Also, what is the HTML in question?

Comment: see recent edit guys thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

this code give me what I want

```
# not sure about this but it works (I was getting blocked by something and this the way I found around it)
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

#this grabs the all the text from the page
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')

#this is for selecting all the games in from 1 to 100 (the list of them)
game_containers = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")

# print(game_containers)

game_names = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")[0].text.strip()
game_metascores_p = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game positive")[0].text.strip()
game_metascores_m = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game mixed")[0].text.strip()
game_user_s = html_soup.find_all("span", class_="data textscore textscore_favorable")[0].text.strip()

# print(game_names)
# print(game_metascores_m or game_metascores_p)
# print(game_user_s)

#lists to store the data
names = []
metascores = []
userscores = []

#Extract data from each game
for games in game_containers:

#     game_names = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")[0].text.strip()
#     game_metascores_p = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game positive")[0].text.strip()
#     game_metascores_m = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game mixed")[0].text.strip()
#     game_user_s = html_soup.find_all("span", class_="data textscore textscore_favorable")[0].text.strip()


    name = games.find()
    names.append(name.text.strip())


#     metascore = games.find("div", class_="product_item product_title") or games.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game mixed")
#     print(metascore)

# print(game_metascores_p)
```

doesnt give me the metascore thought and I don't know why